# Silence emacs warning

Tags: emacs

Whenever I try to save my emacs file, it prompts me "*file* has changed since visited or saved. Save anyway? (yes/no)". I tried "diff buffer-with-file" but it says there's no difference. I'm suspecting this is happening because I'm using a virtual machine with shared file. Anyway, I want to silence this error, and save without prompt. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If this is only happening for a particular file in a particular Emacs instance, you can try `M-x revert-buffer` to replace the buffer with the contents of the file. That should reset the timer to what's on disk. Of course you will lose any unsaved changes, but you say you have none.

If this doesn't work, or you are getting this error for every file every time you run Emacs, you are in bigger trouble than I know how to diagnose.

Comment: This is sadly for almost every file I open.